# Add column to data frame with column names of selected options

Tags: r, dataframe

So if i have a data frame like the following:

```
df = data.frame(cbind(c(0,0,1,0), c(1,0,0,1), c(1,1,0,0)))
df
  X1 X2 X3
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
```

I would like to add a fouth column to the dataframe with a comma delmited list of the columns names where a 1 is presenet.

So for row 1 I would like a "summary" column with "X2, X3"

I have tried

```
apply(df[c(1:3)], function(x) {
    if (x == 1)
    {
      df$summary = paste(df$summary, names(x), sep = ",")
    }
 })
```

But I think I'm not understanding the (x) in function(x)

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
df$summary <- apply(df, 1, function(x)paste(colnames(df)[x==1], collapse=","))
```